# Regular Expressions in (Oracle) SQL to split date/time into separate date and time columns

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, syntax

I am trying to split date and time from a column that contains both date and time using a regular expression.

Ex-
Current:

```
+------------------------------+
|           original           |
+------------------------------+
| 21-JAN-16 01.20.51.097679 PM |
| 02-FEB-16 01.32.53.469568 PM |
| 01-DEC-15 06.00.41.315710 AM |
| 14-JAN-16 04.11.53.107373 PM |
| 21-JAN-16 01.05.15.113135 PM |
| 03-FEB-16 12.06.10.128735 PM |
| 04-FEB-16 06.24.59.557983 PM |
+------------------------------+
```

Desired:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|    date     |    time     |
+-------------+-------------+
| 21-JAN-2016 | 01:20:51 PM |
| 02-FEB-2016 | 01:32:53 PM |
| 01-DEC-2015 | 06:00:41 AM |
| 14-JAN-2016 | 04:11:53 PM |
| 21-JAN-2016 | 01:05:15 PM |
| 03-FEB-2016 | 12:06:10 PM |
| 04-FEB-2016 | 06:24:59 PM |
+-------------+-------------+
```

The data type is VARCHAR2.

Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT
REGEXP_REPLACE(original,
  '([[:digit:]]{2})\-([[:alpha:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{2})\ ([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,}\.([[:alpha:]]{2}))',
  '\1-\2-20\3') "date",

REGEXP_REPLACE(original,
  '([[:digit:]]{2})\-([[:alpha:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{2})\ ([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,}\.([[:alpha:]]{2}))',
  '\4:\5:\6 \7') "time"
FROM database.table
```

and here's what I got when I ran the above:

```
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
|             date             |             time             |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| 21-JAN-16 01.20.51.097679 PM | 21-JAN-16 01.20.51.097679 PM |
| 02-FEB-16 01.32.53.469568 PM | 02-FEB-16 01.32.53.469568 PM |
| 01-DEC-15 06.00.41.315710 AM | 01-DEC-15 06.00.41.315710 AM |
| 14-JAN-16 04.11.53.107373 PM | 14-JAN-16 04.11.53.107373 PM |
| 21-JAN-16 01.05.15.113135 PM | 21-JAN-16 01.05.15.113135 PM |
| 03-FEB-16 12.06.10.128735 PM | 03-FEB-16 12.06.10.128735 PM |
| 04-FEB-16 06.24.59.557983 PM | 04-FEB-16 06.24.59.557983 PM |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

Not too sure where I went wrong?

Comment: What you got means nothing was replaced, in either attempt. Which means that the regular expressions you wrote weren't matched on the input strings. Almost certainly the reason (or one of the major reasons) is that you are using the backslash incorrectly. It should only be used to escape things that need to be escaped. For example, space doesn't need to be escaped. Dash doesn't need to be escaped (it is a regular character, except in a character class where it can't be escaped anyway). Etc.

Comment: Of course all of this sturm and drang could be avoided by correcting your data model. Dates and times should _always_ be stored in either DATE or some variant of TIMESTAMP.   Both data types contain both date and time components, and separating the two is a simple matter of correct use of the TO_CHAR function.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle has a wide variety of functions to work with date and time.  How about this which [reduces your problem](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(original, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM') as ORIGINAL_VALUE,
TO_TIMESTAMP(original, 'DD-MON-RR') AS DATE_ONLY,
TO_TIMESTAMP(original, 'HH:MI:SS.FF AM') AS TIME_ONLY
from database.table;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your data is very regular, I wouldn't use a regexp at all. SUBSTR works fine.

```
-- sample data
with orig as (select '21-JAN-16 01.20.51.097679 PM' as dt from dual)
-- query
select substr(dt,1,9) as d, substr(dt,11) as t
from orig;
```

But the problem in your regexp is that your last `\.` should be `\` - it's a space before PM, not a period. And you don't need to escape spaces, so it can just be

```
'([[:digit:]]{2})\-([[:alpha:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{2}) ([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,} ([[:alpha:]]{2}))'
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't work with dates and times as strings; you should use the appropriate data types:

- Use a `TIMESTAMP` data type for a date and time with fractional seconds.
- Use a `DATE` data type for a date (and, if necessary truncate the time component back to midnight).
- Use an `INTERVAL` data type if you want a time without a date.

So, you can use:

```sql
SELECT TRUNC( datetime ) AS "date",
       datetime - TRUNC( datetime ) AS "time"
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( original, 'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM' ) AS datetime
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which will output (depending on your NLS settings):

> ```
> date      | time                         
> :-------- | :----------------------------
> 21-JAN-16 | +000000000 13:20:51.097679000
> 02-FEB-16 | +000000000 13:32:53.469568000
> 01-DEC-15 | +000000000 06:00:41.315710000
> 14-JAN-16 | +000000000 16:11:53.107373000
> 21-JAN-16 | +000000000 13:05:15.113135000
> 03-FEB-16 | +000000000 12:06:10.128735000
> 04-FEB-16 | +000000000 18:24:59.557983000
> ```

If you really want to use strings then convert the string to the most appropriate data type (`TIMESTAMP`) and then use `TO_CHAR` to convert it back to a string with the desired format model:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( datetime, 'DD-MON-YYYY' ) AS "date",
       TO_CHAR( datetime, 'HH12.MI.SS AM' ) AS "time"
FROM   (
  SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP( original, 'DD-MON-RR HH12.MI.SS.FF6 AM' ) AS datetime
  FROM   table_name
)
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> date        | time       
> :---------- | :----------
> 21-JAN-2016 | 01.20.51 PM
> 02-FEB-2016 | 01.32.53 PM
> 01-DEC-2015 | 06.00.41 AM
> 14-JAN-2016 | 04.11.53 PM
> 21-JAN-2016 | 01.05.15 PM
> 03-FEB-2016 | 12.06.10 PM
> 04-FEB-2016 | 06.24.59 PM
> ```

To answer the question you asked:

> Not too sure where I went wrong?

You have an `\.` before the final meridian value when you should have a space and the output pattern for the time should be `\4:\5:\6 \8`:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(
         original,
         '([[:digit:]]{2})\-([[:alpha:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{2})\ ([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,} ([[:alpha:]]{2}))',
         '\1-\2-20\3'
       ) "date",
       REGEXP_REPLACE(
         original,
         '([[:digit:]]{2})\-([[:alpha:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{2})\ ([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{2})\.([[:digit:]]{1,} ([[:alpha:]]{2}))',
         '\4:\5:\6 \8'
       ) "time"
FROM   table_name
```

Outputs:

> ```
> date        | time       
> :---------- | :----------
> 21-JAN-2016 | 01:20:51 PM
> 02-FEB-2016 | 01:32:53 PM
> 01-DEC-2015 | 06:00:41 AM
> 14-JAN-2016 | 04:11:53 PM
> 21-JAN-2016 | 01:05:15 PM
> 03-FEB-2016 | 12:06:10 PM
> 04-FEB-2016 | 06:24:59 PM
> ```

You could simplify the regular expression by getting rid of the unnecessary escape characters and using perl-style character groups rather than POSIX ones:

```
^(\d{2})-([A-Z]{3})-(\d{2}) (\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{2})\.(\d{1,}) ([AP]M)$
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c2f4d9d9c2dfc33a0ef791f22d1de228)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
to_char(to_timestamp(s, 'dd-MON-RR hh12.mi.ss.ff6 PM'), 'dd-MON-yyyy') s1, 
to_char(to_timestamp(s, 'dd-MON-RR hh12.mi.ss.ff6 PM'), 'hh12.mi.ss PM') s2
from t
```

Answer (score 0):

If your column `original` is `varchar2` then you need to convert it to `timestamp` amd then back to date and time separately as follows:

```
select 
to_char(to_timestamp(original,'dd-mon-rr hh.mi.ss.ff PM'), 'dd-mon-rr') as "DATE",
to_char(to_timestamp(original,'dd-mon-rr hh.mi.ss.ff PM'), 'hh:mi:ss PM') as "TIME",
from your_table
```

Cheers!!